# can't load open weather map icons

Tags: android

I am working with this http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2013/05/build-weather-app-json-http-android.html tutorial to learn how use weather services in my app. I run this tutorial and it works fine. But I've got one problem. Can't load icons. Logcat error is

```
java.io.FileNotFoundExeption: http://openweathermap.org/img/w/ at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionTmpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnctionTmpl.java:186)
```

When I open this link in Chrome I can see the image so I don't know why it can't be found.
code is there https://github.com/survivingwithandroid/Surviving-with-android/tree/master/WeatherApp
Error in line 87 of file "WeatherHttpClient.java"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to load a directory as file stream. Not sure why this should cause a FileNotFoundException but it's worth trying with the URL: `http://openweathermap.org/img/w/<one-of-the-files>.png`

At least the file should be possible to open.

Answer (score 1):

facing the same issue just change your **url** like bellow and its working fine
https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/50d@4x.png

Answer (score 0):

add .png file ext

example

con = (HttpURLConnection) ( new URL(IMG_URL + code +".png")).openConnection();